# How to grab most popular rows in table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with comments almost 2 million rows.  We receive roughly 500 new comments per day.  Each comment is assigned to a specific ID.  I want to grab the most popular "discussions" based on the specific ID.

I have an index on the ID column.

What is best practice?  Do I just group by this ID and then sort by the ID who has the most comments?  Is this most efficient for a table this size?

Comment: What is considered "*most popular*"? The top 10 discussions with the most comments? Top 50? Are you narrowing discussions down that are after a particular date?

Comment: Best practice would be to keep it simple and write a normal SELECT query, like Zane's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Do I just group by this ID and then sort by the ID who has the most comments?

That's pretty much simply how I would do it. Let's just assume you want to retrieve the top 50:

```
SELECT id
FROM comments
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

If your users are executing this query quite frequently in your application and you're finding that it's not running quite as fast as you'd like, one way you could optimize it is to store the result of the above query in a separate table (`topdiscussions`), and perhaps have a script or cron that runs intermittently every five minutes or so which would update that table.

Then in your application, just have your users select from the `topdiscussions` table so that they only need to select from **50** rows rather than **2 million**.

The downside of this of course being that the selection will no longer be in real-time, but rather out of sync by up to five minutes or however often you want to update the table. How real-time you actually need it to be depends on the requirements of your system.

**Edit**: As per your comments to this answer, I know a little more about your schema and requirements. The following query retrieves the discussions that are the most active within the past day:

```
SELECT a.id, etc...
FROM discussions a
INNER JOIN comments b ON 
    a.id = b.discussion_id AND 
    b.date_posted > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT 50
```

I don't know your field names, but that's the general idea.

Comment: You are relying on illogical and non-standard behaviour. A better DB will give you an error similar to [`Column 'xyz' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx). A more appropriate solution would be to select just the discussion id and comment count, then fetch the discussions/comments themselves through a join.

Comment: @DCoder, two reasons why I wrote it the way I did: **1)** I do not know anything about the OP's DB structure or the columns he/she needs to be selecting. Perhaps the `id` is linked to another table called `discussions` where you would need a join to get information about discussions / or perhaps the comments table is denormalized and also contains the discussion title, user_id, etc. etc. **2)** This is clearly tagged as MySQL which allows for this. I'm only wanting to show the simplest example based on the information provided.

Comment: Yes, the ID is linked to another table, you are correct.  And also, I'd need it by date.  So if I want to say, give me the top 50 discussions around ID for yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the ID indicates the discussion to which a comment is attached.  So, first you would need some notion of most popular.
1) Initialize a "Comment total" table by counting up comments by ID and setting a column called 'delta' to 0.

2) Periodically

2.1) Count the comments by ID

2.2) Subtract the old count from the new count and store the value into the delta column.

2.3) Replace the count of comments with the new count.

3) Select the 10 'hottest' discussions by selecting 10 row from comment total in order of descending delta.

Now the rest is trivial.  That's just the comments whose discussion ID matches the ones you found in step 3.